# how i can send post data array angular and get data on api laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

i have code like it on angular
my array :
[{"kode":"123","nama":"satu dua tiga"},{"kode":"321","nama":"tiga dua satu"}]

```
$http({
     method: 'POST',
     url: 'api/insertCustomerArr',
     data: myarray
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

}, function errorCallback(response) {

});
```

and how i can get this data on controller laravel and how i can looping ?

```
public function insertCustomerArr(Request $request)
{
  echo count($request);

  exit;
}
```

this code result count 1, how i can get data?

Comment: Have you var_dump($request)? Is the data you need in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check using

```
return $request->all();
```

this will return all the data you posted from angular request

Comment: how i can get data just column 0 for looping?

Comment: can you share what you are getting in $request->all();

Answer (score 0):

Laravel $request object has a request property inside of it.

So that basically `$request->request->all();` should contain all the data that came from angular.